# aspnet core does not capture my json data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fetch, fetch-api

js ->

```
var favoriteIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".favoriteIcon");
    favoriteIcons.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var itemPPElement = item.parentElement.parentElement;
            var id = itemPPElement.id;
            var customer_id = itemPPElement.querySelector(".customer_id").value;
            var product_id = itemPPElement.querySelector(".product_id").value;
            var jsonObject = {
                favorite_id: id,
                customer_id: customer_id,
                product_id: product_id
            };
            console.log(jsonObject);
            fetch('/Favorite/SwitchFavorite', {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                headers: { 
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                item.classList.toggle("la-heart");
                item.classList.toggle("la-heart-o");
                console.log(json);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
    });
```

Controller ->

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SwitchFavorite(Favorite favorite)
        {
            return Json(favorite);
        }
```

[image]

I will capture my json data in the controller and process it, but I return the incoming data directly to control my data, but it does not capture the data. what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SwitchFavorite(Favorite favorite)
{
   return Json(favorite);
}
```

to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SwitchFavorite([FromBody]Favorite favorite)
{
   return Json(favorite);
}
```